# 404 in Firefox only

Tags: php, codeigniter, cross-browser

I'm building a web application with CodeIgniter and about 15 minutes ago I decided to do some cross-browser testing.

Thankfully I did, as none of the pages will load inside Firefox.

The homepage will load when I enter the address directly, but every time I click on a link, the site is returning CI's default 404 page, which I find quite bizarre considering this problem does not exist in Safari or Chrome.

A few things to note:

- I am running Firefox 10.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.
- The application is installed on my local server running XAMPP.
- I have removed index.php from my URLs.

Has anybody experienced something like this before?

Thanks.

Comment: Checked your access log to see how FF's requested urls differ from those in the other browsers?

Comment: @Madmartigan Yes. About 25 times, haha. It's boggling my mind!

Comment: @MarcB I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: Don't know where Apache on mac would keep them, but the location should be specified in the httpd.conf somewhere.

Comment: Do you get different URLs in each browser?

Comment: As suggested, check the URL and Javascript/cookies configuration on Firefox.

As a side note: if you are doing cross-browser testing you should also try your site on Internet Explorer (at least versions 7-8-9) that is one (or the most) diffuse browser. I know you are on Mac but you should really test this.

Comment: @SalmanA No. They're the same URLs across all browsers.

Comment: Check your Apache logs in Xampp, check to make sure it's serving the right page when Firefox requests it. If you're sure you haven't changed any settings in Firefox, check what http headers are being sent to servers by Firefox and investigate

Answer (score 0):

try purge your browser cache and try again (and the cookie)

Comment: He has tried that about 25 times in the comments section of the question

Comment: i see it after sorry but you say purge the cache not the cookie if you already do it also sorry for this useless answer